# Constructing fast queries using janusgraph

Tags: graph-theory, janusgraph

I have a graph that is supposed to track the number of features that a certain user has access to.

There are about 40 users and 4,000 features. All users have access to a core set of default features. About half of the features are shared: 2,000 features. So the graph has no less than 80,000 edges. (I do have a lot of edges going to a shared set of relatively static features. This *is* a problem, but not the focus of this post.)

Given a user's id (UUID) how can I construct a query that will efficiently retrieve all the features that user has access to? My current query looks like this:

```
val graph = // my graph
val query = 
  graph
    .V(user)
    .out("user-feature")
    .has("type", "feature") // Interestingly, removing this makes the query slower
    .dedup()
    .valueMap("feature-name", "id")
    .toList
```

Which will give me a list of `Map[String, String]` representation of all the features to which this user has access. But the query time is approximately 30 seconds. I'd like to cut that time down by half. Is there something I can do to the query, without altering the data-structure (for now), that will help reduce the time?